# Free Video tutorials about Web Usability and Accessibility

Tags: website-design

What are free Video tutorials about **Web Usability** available on net? from Basic to advanced.

Do you have any good links?

I found some:

Web Form Design

http://videos.visitmix.com/mix09/c17f

Web Usability: As Few Clicks As Possible

http://www.dailyblogtips.com/web-usability-as-few-clicks-as-possible/

Web Usability as Quality Assurance

http://web-coord.soe.ucsc.edu/sites/default/files/11/usability-part1.mov

UX: Fundamentals: Focus

http://membership.thinkvitamin.com/library/ux/fundamentals/focus

How User-Friendly Is Your Site?

http://demogirl.com/2008/03/25/how-user-friendly-is-your-site/

Type Ahead Find and Focus

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/ykmh/ykmh-01-focus/

Judge a Web App By Its Title

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/ykmh/ykmh-02-title/

**Some more Videos** **51 July 2010**

Usability Testing - Steve Krug

http://www.peachpit.com/podcasts/episode.aspx?e=F6578A16-F53E-489E-93CF-2C839EA840CF

http://boagworld.com/usability/usability-demo

Usability Testing - Jared Spool

http://5by5.tv/bigwebshow/7

Videos with disabled users

Not really usability testing videos but a video about how disabled users use assistive technology to overcome their learning disability, blindness, dyslexia, etc.

http://www.doit.wisc.edu/accessibility/video/

The 'Mom Test' for Website Usability Testing with Matt Bailey

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKru8BK4P58

Example of Usability Testing

http://www.webmarketingresources.net/Video/Examples_of_User_testing.wmv

Comment: Great question... thanks for posting it... I could really use some good videos to learn from as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for since it's a general topic and you're asking about all levels.

Useful Usability has a good post, [10 Must-See Usability Videos](http://www.usefulusability.com/10-must-see-usability-videos/) that may have some of what you're looking for.

There are a lot of good PodCasts/Webinars out there that aren't free, many worth paying for, like [User Interface Engineering](http://www.uie.com/) (to name just one because I like Jared Spool - @jmspool).

Answer (score 4):

Check out ["25 User Experience Videos That Are Worth Your Time"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/05/25-user-experience-videos-that-are-worth-your-time/)

Answer (score 3):

There's a site called [Usable Efficiency](http://www.usable-efficiency.com/) and it contains videos talking about usability and some coding tips. The site only has 5 videos so far covering usability mistakes, forms, white space and the use of PNG files. I found the one about forms to be more insightful. Hope it helps.